# Assigning a value to an icCube Event in Reporting

Tags: reporting, olap, iccube

1. I am using icCube 5.0 Reporting
2. I want to assign the value of an Event to that returned by the icCube MDX function UserName()--sort of like @{eventname} = UserName().
3. Eventually, @{eventname:reportParm} will be sent to a launched report for use in a filter.

Does anyone have any hints for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clean way (already in [todo](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-142) list)

For the time being there is no clean way. You've to create a Constant - not an event - in Configuration/Constants that you call for example

```
ic3c-userName
```

Assign a javascript expression

```
:ic3reporting.context_.userInfo().name()
```

So you've now an event with the name of the user as value you can use.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked perfectly.  Be sure to make a constant and not an event.

Answer (score 2):

From version 5.0.3 you can use the new syntax.
For user name:

```
:ic3reporting.userName()
```

also you can access the report's name by

```
:ic3reporting.reportName()
```

Comment: Very nice additions.  Thank you.