# IcCube Reporting, how to retrieve userName from javascript?

Tags: javascript, iccube-reporting

Thanks to this post :
 [Assigning a value to an icCube Event in Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536121/assigning-a-value-to-an-iccube-event-in-reporting),

I'm able to get the current username in a widget using a constant (not an event).
But, I can't retrieve it in the report's javascript...

Is there a way to do that?

I need it to be able to show or hide some widgets depending on which user (or role) is connected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get current username paste this code into "Report Javascript"

```
var currentUserName = "Unknown";                                                              
function consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                
  if (event.name == 'ic3-report-init') {                                 
    currentUserName = event.value.context.userInfo().name();
    alert("time to hide widgets for: " + currentUserName);
  }                                                                      
}
```

Comment: Accepted answer, Txs.